# Elasticsearch: Does a query with filtering get affected by relevancy of records not in the filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Imagine I have three sets of data (SetA, SetB, SetC) and three customers. My first customer has access to SetA and SetB, my second customer has access to SetA and SetC and the third uses SetB and SetC. I could create an elasticsearch index per-customer so each index would have the following sets of data...

```
Index1    Index2    Index3
------    ------    ------
SetA      SetA      SetB
SetB      SetC      SetC
```

I then query the correct index based on the customer. This is simple but does involve duplication of the data.

Instead of this I could create a single index with all three sets of data.

```
Index
-----
SetA 
SetB
SetC
```

Then I would add filtering in the query so that only records from the correct sets are considered for the results. This would work but I am concerned that this single index solution would not give identical results for the queries as it would have for the multiple indexes approach.

I think, but am happy to be corrected if wrong, the index is going to take into account all the records in the index when it comes to internal scoring like relevancy and frequency. Therefore the single index with filtering will not given identical results to the multiple-index approach. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Is your concern about the customers' access or about the scoring then? W/ regards to the latter, you could simply add a meta field to each of the sets and boost those fields at query time. In other words, the scoring is overridable.

Comment: My concern is trying to get identical results from the two approaches.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are first, filtering the results based on your customer-id and then only searching, then there would be no impact on the relevance and **you can and you should combine these data in Elasticsearch, rather than creating 3 different indices for this purpose.**

You can read more about the [query and filter contex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html)t and [their impact on the score.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489304/4039431)

Let me show you, by a small example:

### Index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "setA": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "setB": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "setC": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "customer-id": {
                "type": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index two sample docs for each customer

```
{
    "setA" : "first customer",
    "setB" : "first customer",
    "setC" : "",
    "customer-id" : 1
}

{
    "setA" : "first customer set A",
    "setB" : "first customer set B",
    "setC" : "",
    "customer-id" : 1
}

{
    "setA" : "second customer",
    "setC" : "second customer",
    "customer-id" : 2
}

{
    "setA" : "second customer set A",
    "setC" : "second customer set C",
    "customer-id" : 2
}
{
    "setB" : "third customer",
    "setC" : "third customer",
    "customer-id" : 3
}

{
    "setB" : "third customer set A",
    "setC" : "third customer set C",
    "customer-id" : 3
}
```

### Search query by first filtering the first customer and then searching with the relevance score

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [ --> this would match and order according to relevance score
                {
                    "match": {
                        "setA": "first"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [ --> this is used for filtering all docs for cust-1
                {
                    "term": {
                        "customer-id": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so_query_filter",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.8025915, --> relevance is high
                "_source": {
                    "setA": "first customer",
                    "setB": "first customer",
                    "setC": "",
                    "customer-id": 1 --> only cust-1 doc
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "so_query_filter",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.60996956, -> relavance is low as more words than first
                "_source": {
                    "setA": "first customer set A",
                    "setB": "first customer set B",
                    "setC": "",
                    "customer-id": 1 --> only cust-1 doc
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I am not sure this proves it would give the same answer

Comment: @PhilWright, did you create a separate test index and tried it ?